# Converting cURL to Ajax and getting back Error 400

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to store specific urls into jsonbox. However, I have been getting Error 400.

The curl command from the documentation is as below:

```
curl -X POST 'https://jsonbox.io/demobox_6d9e326c183fde7b' \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
    -d '{"name": "Jon Snow", "age": 25}'
```

Below is my edited code, putting in the link for jsonbox and URL as the data.

```
function send_request(url) {
    this.url = url;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonbox.io/box_89ad34d6d995aeb9ebb4',
        type: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(this.url),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(){
          alert("Cannot get data");
        }
})
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: It is not clear from your question if the request generally fails, or if the curl command works fine, but the ajax request does not.

Comment: The curl command is from the documentation, then I adapted it to ajax as I am implementing it on a simple website. The purpose of the function is to send a json data to jsonbox for storage. All of the JS code works fine except this, so I think the ajax request does not. Am converting curl commands to ajax wrongly? I am new to curl and ajax, so any help would be beneficial :)

Comment: This is the link to the documentation: https://github.com/vasanthv/jsonbox

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the payload. Not sure why are you sending the url with your POST request. Check this working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var payload = {
    "name": "Maria", 
    "age": 78
  }
  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonbox.io/demobox_6d9e326c183fde7b',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(payload), 
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(){
      console.log("Cannot get data");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```